# CdkDropList table

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I am trying to generate a table which consist of users and their userstories, and the headers consist of the current status they are in.
Now I would like to create CdkDropLists for the entire table so that I can move userstories between users and different statuses. However I am struggling to connect all these lists together. I would like to have a list of all my CdkDropLists available in my HTML so that I can connect them to eachother.

I looked around on the internet for solutions, but I find it difficult to come up with one.

For now all lists have the same #name, but I required the ability to generate names and link all those lists together. So that the Drag and Drop functionality works within the table.

```html
<table>
  <tr><th></th><th>to do</th><th>doing</th><th>test</th><th>done</th></tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let user of users"><td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td *ngFor="let status of status">
      <div cdkDropList
           [cdkDropListData]="getStatusStories(user.id, status.name)"
           [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="unasignedList"
           (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event, user.id, status.name)"
           #dropList="cdkDropList" style="width: 25%; border: 1px solid black;">
         <div cdkDrag *ngFor="let story of getStatusStories(user.id, status.name)" class="item">{{story.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
private sprints: Sprint[];
private userStories: Userstory[];
private users: User[];
private status: Status[] = [
  { id: "1", name: "to do" } as Status,
  { id: "2", name: "doing" } as Status,
  { id: "3", name: "test" } as Status,
  { id: "4", name: "done" } as Status
];

ngOnInit() {
  this.firebaseService.getSprints().subscribe(sprints => (this.sprints = sprints));
  this.firebaseService.getStories().subscribe(stories => (this.userStories = stories));
  this.firebaseService.getUsers().subscribe(users => (this.users = users));
}

getStatusStories(userId: string, statusName: string): Userstory[] {
  const filteredStories = [];
  this.userStories.forEach(element => {
    if (element.status === statusName && element.user_id === userId) {
      filteredStories.push(element);
    }
  });
  return filteredStories;
}
```